# Stacked and grouped bar chart with ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Hello everyone I am trying to create a plot like the image

I want household to be the x-axis with household numbers and ELI, VLI, LI, and MI being the y-axis values. The ELI, VLI, LI, and MI values should be additive as displayed in the example.

```
household<-c("Extremely low income", "Very low income", "Low income",     
"Middle income")
householdnumbers<-c("3,000","3,015","5,175","12,255")
ELI<-c("1,885","1,885","1,885","1,885")
VLI<-c("0","3,500","3,500","3,500")
LI<-c("0","0","14,385","14,385")
MI<-c("0","0","0","5,085")

housing<-data.frame(household,householdnumbers,ELI,VLI,LI,MI)
```

Thank you so much for any help.

[image: bar chart example]

Comment: Is it correct that `ELI`, `VLI`, `LI` , `MI` and `householdnumbers` are characters? Do you want perfectly that plot or a plor with different colors etc. is ok?

Comment: Hello, yes it is true they are characters. Colors do not matter much at this point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m<-melt(housing, id.vars = "household", measure.vars = c("ELI", "VLI","LI","MI"))
m$household <- factor(m$household, levels = c("Extremely low income", "Very low income", "Low income", "Middle income"))
ggplot(data = m, aes(x = household, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack')+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

here is my edited version using base r:

```
householdnumbers<-c(3000,3015,5175,12255)
ELI<-c(1885,1885,1885,1885)
VLI<-c(0,3500,3500,3500)
LI<-c(0,0,14385,14385)
MI<-c(0,0,0,5085)
housing<-data.frame(household,householdnumbers,ELI,VLI,LI,MI)
barplot(t(housing[,!names(housing) %in% c("householdnumbers","household")]),space = 2,width = 0.5,names.arg=household,legend.text =c("ELI","VLI","LI","MI"),col=c("red","green","pink","blue"),args.legend = list(x = 'topleft'))
barplot(as.vector(housing[,names(housing) %in% c("householdnumbers")]), space = c(3,2,2,2), width = 0.5,add=T,args.legend = list(x = 'left'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer shirin, your example does create the stacked bars however I am also looking to add a second set of bars to the plot like the example posted above.

Comment: @garrettsmith I edited my answer see if that gives you what you want!